# What is a good design for a REST URI in case of several pages of results?

Tags: rest, uri

Say I have a service I want to expose via REST.
A query on the service may yield a long list of results, which are returned "page by page", which is why the user must be able to:

- specify an ordering criterion (alpha sorting on the values of one attribute or another)
- specify a key value from where to get results: "show me results from letter C on..."
- specify a page number from which to start getting results (i.e. I want to get the results from page 3 )
- specify the max number of results per page

I suppose the ordering criterion is well suited to a query string parameter, since it does not belong to the resource, but is just a preference for its returned representation.

What about the other options? Is the whole idea sound, or it smells too much of its web-oriented origin?

As a side note, have you got any pointers for good overall design suggestions for heavy queries with multiple pages of results (for example policies for caching results on the server)?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [RESTful Web Services Cookbook](http://books.google.com/books?id=LDuzpQlVuG4C&lpg=PP1&hl=fr&pg=PP1#v=onepage&q&f=false):

## Request

```
GET /book?sortbyDesc=date&limit=5
```

## Response

```
{
"id": 9,
"links": [{
  "href": "/book?sortByDesc=date&limit=5&start=5",
  "rel": "next"}]
}
```

Comment: Great, just downloaded that book